# How dnf/yum decides to refresh or do not refresh repositories?

Tags: yum, rpm, dnf

When I try to install a package say `git` using:

```
dnf install -y git
```

in the very same virtual machine image dnf/yum sometimes simply installs the package, but sometimes, usually if some time spent after the latest dnf/yum usage it starts to update repositories like:

```
AlmaLinux 9 - AppStream                         4.7 MB/s | 8.0 MB     00:01
...and so on on all configured and enabled repositories
```

How dnf/yum decides when to update and when do not update? I am installing the very same package on the very same image... so the linux and package manager state is supposedly alse same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those not having Red Hat account answer can be found [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/yum.conf), under `metadata_expire` parameter.
Also `man yum.conf` will give useful information.

On my Rocky Linux 9.1 system this parameter is set inside almost every "`rocky`" repo contained in `/etc/yum.repos.d/rocky*.repo` files.
You can see it under one of the repos:

```
[baseos]
name=Rocky Linux $releasever - BaseOS
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.rockylinux.org/mirrorlist?arch=$basearch&repo=BaseOS-$releasever$rltype
#baseurl=http://dl.rockylinux.org/$contentdir/$releasever/BaseOS/$basearch/os/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
countme=1
metadata_expire=6h
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-Rocky-9
```

Comment: Many thx. I see some files, in which the `metadata_expire` is not defined, is there a default for this?

Comment: Yes, due to `man dnf.conf` it is 48h, and you can confirm that with `yum repolist -v` (search for `Repo-expire` line, you will see `172800 second(s)`, which is 48h. If `metadata_expire` is not set in the `/etc/dnf.conf` file, nor in `/etc/yum.repos.d/<some_repo>.repo`, default is 48h. If it is set in both places, latter one takes precedence. You can play with `metadata_expire`, let's say comment them all (in all places), try `yum install <pkg>` a few times. Set small value (60) to only one repo and try again `yum install <pkg>` inside and outside of 60 seconds frame.

Answer (score 3):

[According to RH](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3430121) this is managed by `metadata_expire` parameter. The default value is 6 hours.